# Event handler affects in garbage collection in CLR

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, garbage-collection, eventhandler

I'm completely confused about how event handler can affect in garbage collection operation.

For example, why object a1 not collected by garbage collection ( the destructor of a1 is not calling):

Even after unsubscribing timeChange eventHandler the destructor isn't called by garbage collector.

Best regards.

```
public class B
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        A a1 = new A();
        a1.timeChange += A1_timeChange;

        a1.Start();

        a1 = null;

        GC.Collect();
    }

    private void A1_timeChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((DateTime)sender).ToString() );
    }
}

public class A
{
    ~A()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A Collected");
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (timeChange != null)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (true)
                {
                    timeChange(DateTime.Now, null);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler timeChange;
}
```

Comment: The task keeps it referenced through the `this.timeChange` member, `this` becoming undefined would be disastrous.  The while (true) loop ensures it stays referenced forever.  Arbitrarily make the event static and you'll now see it getting collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In summary**
It is not the event itself that is causing this, but rather referencing an instance member of class A from a long running thread using a closure.

**The event itself is not the issue, or is it?**
This code `a1.timeChange += A1_timeChange;` causes a delegate inside class A that implements the event `public event EventHandler timeChange` to reference `A1_timeChange` inside class B.
So, the reference is the *other way around*
In your scenario, if you got rid of all references to class B, but did not unsubscribe from the event, then the event handler in A that points to a handler method in B could keep class B reachable, and therefore not GC'ed

**What is really happening**
Your class A is accessible from one of the GC roots (specifically, actively running threads), it's still reachable and therefore, not collected - [read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#what_happens_during_a_garbage_collection)

You have spawned an eternally running task (well it will stop when the app closes / foreground thread terminates) with this code

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                while (true)
                {
                    timeChange(DateTime.Now, null);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
```

The thing is, that you're using a lambda that closes over the `timeChange` event, and that makes a compiler to generate a class that simply references class A

One more thing, just by having a descructor (which is compiled to a finalizer) you prolong the lifetime of your object by one GC collection - on the first GC, your object will be marked as unreachable, and will be put onto finalization queue. And on the *next* GC, the finalizer will actually run - [read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#manipulating_unmanaged_resources)